# Directed Acyclical Graph Traversal... help?

Tags: graph, traversal, directed-acyclic-graphs

a little out of my depth here and need to phone a friend. I've got a directed acyclical graph I need to traverse and I'm stumbling into to graph theory for the first time. I've been reading a lot about it lately but unfortunately I don't have time to figure this out academically. Can someone give me a kick with some help as to how to process this tree?

Here are the rules:

- there are *n* root nodes (I call them "sources")
- there are *n* end nodes
- source nodes carry a numeric value
- downstream nodes (I call them "worker" nodes) preform various operations on the incoming values like Add, Mult, etc.

As you can see from the graph below, nodes `a`, `b`, and `c` need to be processed before `d`, `e`, or `f`.

**What's the proper order to walk this tree?**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would look into linearization of DAGs which should be achievable through Topological sorts.

Linearization, from what I remember, basically sorts in an order which holds to the invariant that for all nodes (Node_X) that have an outdegree to any other given node `NodeA`, `NodeX` appears before `NodeA`.

This would mean that, from your example, nodes a,b, and d would be processed first. Node c second. Nodes e and f, last.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: I'm currently storing a node and it's downstream neighbors for every entry into the graph ([guided by this](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs.html)). I'm starting to think I need to forgo this and store the edges separately. Do you have a storage format suggestion that might make these dependency comparisons easier?

Comment: @vfxcode - it might help if each node has a list of upstream parents.

Comment: Actually a list of the parent nodes for a given node, as missingno suggested, would help in checking if the node being iterated over has any further incoming edges. If not, you would insert it into list S. I'm referring to the algorithm outlined in the Wikipedia page for Topological sort.

Comment: I guess the last thing I'm confused about (sorry) is the direction of traversal. Since I'm checking for know inputs, am I walking upstream, checking nodes at random, or walking downstream?

Comment: Not too sure about what you might mean, but in the algorithm you start out with a list of source nodes S (the "top"). Then as you enumerate over S. When enumerating a given element s of S, you remove all edges (s,v) where v is a "child" of s. If v no longer has an incoming edges (you're checking a level above v here) then you add v to S.

Answer (score 5):

You need to process the nodes via a [Topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). The sort is not necessarily unique so there might be more than one available order (not that this should matter anyway).

The linked wikipedia page should have concrete algorithms to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Nadir's was just a little more elaborate. :)