# Traversing a nested decision tree

Tags: java, algorithm, decision-tree

so I have a json with the following format (its not complete). The top node will be GUID1111:

```
{"GUID1111": {
  title: "Learning C++",
  next: ["GUID1112", "GUID1113"] }
"GUID1112" : {
  title: "Learning C#",
  next ["GUID1115"] }
"GUID1113" : {
  title: "Learning C#",
  next ["GUID1115"] }
"GUID1115" : {
  title: "How to Pay",
  next ["GUID1118","GUID1119","GUID1120"] }...
}
```

For each of the GUID there will be a link to other GUID (more than 2), and some GUIDs can link to the same node. I.e: 1112 and 1113 are linking to 1115 (and maybe some other node, does not need to be only 1).
Can you please suggest a fast way to traverse through this Decision tree? At the end I would like to have a collection of workflow like:

```
WF1: GUID1111, GUID1112, GUID1115, GUID1118
WF2: GUID1111, GUID1112, GUID1115, GUID1119
WF3: GUID1111, GUID1112, GUID1115, GUID1120
WF4: GUID1111, GUID1113, GUID1115, GUID1118
WF5: GUID1111, GUID1113, GUID1115, GUID1119
WF6: GUID1111, GUID1113, GUID1115, GUID1120...
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON...

Comment: How do you determine the first node(s) visited for each workflow?

Comment: You are  looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting . Possible duplicate question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989091/directed-acyclical-graph-traversal-help

Comment: @RohanGrover How does topological sorting apply here? Given the expected output, it looks like only [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) needs to be applied.

Comment: @ljeabmreosn  right you are.  I misunderstood the question. DFS should work.

Comment: Where did `GUID1116` come from in the expected output?  In your starting data structure is `GUID1115` supposed to point at `GUID1116`?

Comment: i clarified my question above. thanks

Comment: @Kiddo My question still applies.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i removed GUID1116